# Is it possible to tell the Fraction class not to reduce to the lowest format

Tags: java

I use [Fraction](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/fraction/Fraction.html) for representing fractions, but the problem is it reduces to the lowest form immediately on providing inputs to the constructor. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

```
e.g. Fraction f1 = new Fraction (1, 3) == 1/3
Fraction f2 = new Fraction (2, 4) == gets reduced to 1/2 but I would rather want it as 2/4
```

How to do this?

Comment: Why? That's what it's supposed to do.

Comment: I would like to perform certain operations prior to obtaining the results in the reduced format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible, unless you switch to [Commons-Lang Fraction](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/math/Fraction.html) instead of Commons-Math.

Comment: Currently we are using commons-math instead of commons-lang and we don't use any advanced functions. What would be the current package to use (not sure what package would be deprecated here)

Comment: Just go with the commons-lang Fraction class because the constructor does not reduce the fraction.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `org.apache.commons.lang.math.Fraction.getReducedFraction(int, int)` use `org.apache.commons.lang.math.Fraction.getFraction(int, int)`

```
System.out.println("fraction: " + Fraction.getFraction(2, 4));
System.out.println("reduced:  " + Fraction.getReducedFraction(2, 4));
```

results in:

```
fraction: 2/4
reduced:  1/2
```

Comment: No, check out the OP's link. The OP is using org.apache.commons.math.fraction and you are using org.apache.commons.lang.math. Commons-math is more advanced than commons-lang.

Comment: Tx @dogbane, I have fixed it.